# Simple question about irreducibility in general and in Noetherian topological space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Referring to the proof of $X$ Noetherian topological space having finitely many irreducible components.

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0050

I have a simple question about irreducible space: Could you please explain why if $Z$ is not a *finite* union of irreducible components means it is not irreducible?

Comment: Isn’t it true that if $Z$ is irreducible, then $Z$ is the unique irreducible component?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I guess so, then any union of more than one irreducible component is 'reducible'. Thanks